# Parse string to array with empty elements in bash

Tags: arrays, bash

folks.
Currently I'm trying to parse `lsblk` output into array for further analysis in bash. The only problem I have is the empty columns that cause `read -a` to shift the fallowing values into incorrect place of the elements that are suppose to be empty. Here is the example:

```
# lsblk -rno MOUNTPOINT,FSTYPE,TYPE,DISC-GRAN 
/usr/portage ext2 loop 4K
  disk 512B
  part 512B
 ext2 part 512B
/ ext4 part 512B
/mnt/extended ext4 part 512B
```

The MOUNTPOINT and FSTYPE of second and third lines are empty as well as MOUNTPOINT of forth line, but 'traditional' read like this:

```
while read -r LINE; do
    IFS=' ' read -a ARRAY <<< $LINE
    echo "${ARRAY[0]};${ARRAY[1]};${ARRAY[2]};${ARRAY[3]}"
done < <(lsblk -rno MOUNTPOINT,FSTYPE,TYPE,DISC-GRAN)
```

Will produce an incorrect result with shifted columns an 0'th and 1'st element filled instead of 2nd and 3rd:

```
/usr/portage;ext2;loop;4K
disk;512B;;
part;512B;;
ext2;part;512B;
/;ext4;part;512B
/mnt/extended;ext4;part;512B
```

So, I wonder if there is some 'elegant' solution of this case or should I just do it the old way like I used to with a help of `string.h` in trusty C?

To be more clear, I need this values as array elements in for loop for analyses, not just to print this. Echoing is done just as an example of misbehavior.

Comment: This would probably be easier in `awk`, as you can check the line format more specifically.

Comment: `tr ' ' ';' < <(lsblk -rno MOUNTPOINT,FSTYPE,TYPE,DISC-GRAN)`

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you specify `-P` option to `lsblk` to output in the form of key="value" pairs and read the output?

Then you can say something like:

```
while read -ra a; do
    for ((i=0; i<${#a[@]}; i++)); do
        a[i]=${a[i]#*=}     # extract rvalue
        a[i]=${a[i]//\"/}   # remove surrounding quotes
    done
    (IFS=';'; echo "${a[*]}")
done < <(lsblk -Pno MOUNTPOINT,FSTYPE,TYPE,DISC-GRAN)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `awk` rather than `bash` for this. Use `NF` to assign the variables depending on how many fields are in the line.

```
awk -v 'OFS=;' 'NF == 4 { mountpoint = $1; fstype = $2; type = $3; gran = $4 }
                NF == 3 { mountpoint = ""; fstype = $1; type = $2; gran = $3 }
                NF == 2 { mountpoint = ""; fstype = ""; type = $1; gran = $2 }
                {print mountpoint, fstype, type, gran}' < <(lsblk -rno MOUNTPOINT,FSTYPE,TYPE,DISC-GRAN)
```